# Knowing when a Table Cell has been viewed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table with custom table cells, is there any way of knowing when they have been viewed, i.e. their contents have been completely shown to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewDelegate defines the method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` so you just need to override that method.

From the Apple docs at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate,

"Tells the delegate the table view is about to draw a cell for a particular row."

Comment: but that tells me when that cell will be drawn not when it has been viewed in full

Comment: Correct, the timing would probably be off a bit. I haven't seen any other way of doing it easily.

Answer (score 2):

After stepping through Apple doc on [TableViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIScrollView). You can get view window's location and determine which cell has been displayed with a boolean (isDisplayed). Of interest:
-contentInset
-contentSize

*When specializing UITableCell, you can add the boolean there.

Hope this helps